Is any action taken against users who consistently repeat AI answers?
It's disheartening to see how while those of us who strive to keep the site active by crafting thoughtful answers, a user keeps getting upvotes based on copy/paste from AI. Seeing this question, I deleted my answer while I was developing it as soon as the CHAT GPT answer was insserted since it invalidated any possible analysis. And this answer has been chosen as valid. The same user who "wrote" the valid answer has the highest number of upvotes of the week, all obtained with AI answers, and it's not just one or two, it's practically all of his/her last answers. And yes, I flagged all of them.
Also it's frustrating to see there is no any public action against this behaviour.

If you have very serious concerns regarding this issue (and users involved), I suggest having a private chat first (with any of the moderators as well as the individuals) before putting the comments publicly as it does mean a slightly different course of action need to be taken (not necessarily the best for everyone). I don't think there is any definitive way to investigate and prove the allegations (beyond obvious breaches that also overlaps with current community policies).

The problem is that this is not an isolated case: the same user posting AI answers all week. As there was no reaction of any kind, I started to comment and the answers gradually began to be deleted, but only the ones I commented on, not the others. Personally, I miss an "official" action, and that's why I post this question here.

The previous network policy relating to AI generated content wasn't exactly well-received (and as expectedly, created a lot of controversy), and since then there has been ongoing discussion and engagement between StackExchange and moderators in terms of what the best path is moving forward.
From my understanding, there isn't a current consensus on how to deal with AI generated content platform wide, and previous research on whether there can be an effective way to help moderators manage the influx of AI generated content did not reach a definitive result (I'll have to find dig up some information on this, but I am sure I made a post or asked a question about it somewhere).
I am also one of those who (hopefully) strives to keep the site active by asking and answering questions, and I would like to think that the benefit of doing so is that it contributes to a wider body of knowledge that I found useful when I first started out in this field.
I believe that the enforcement of rules and policies are only effective if the community as a whole agrees with this, and that it can be applied fairly with the usual safeguards to prevent abuse or misuse by users. I am not quite sure we are at that stage yet as everyone is grappling with the impact and the response to the widespread use of AI technology using LLM.
I can tell you that StackExchange is still having conversations with the moderator group at the moment, and that this is not an issue that we are neglecting but simply having a challenging time finding the right problem to solve, and the best solution.
UPDATE: I found the posts that I made on UXSE Meta from over a year ago, but there wasn't really much response from the community so we didn't take any further action.
Community consensus on enabling a banner to warn about policy on AI-generated content?
Should we be raising the bar on the type and/or quality of questions and answers as a way of filtering out AI assisted or generated content?

A summary of this answer could have been attached to one of my flags and I would have understood the situation without further ado.

@Danielillo I will try to do better in the future, but sadly the job of being a moderator isn't getting easier.

I understand. Thanks for the clarification.

@Danielillo I should add that the moderators are all happy for the community to raise concerns directly or posting questions like you have. It's harder to manage it in the comments and no one really seems use to the chat feature (something I have raised with StackExchange).
